# Когда может потребоваться синхронное ожидание асинхронной операции?

Tags: c#, .net

Если нужно асинхронно дождаться метод, то нужно ставить `await`, которые в свою очередь требует модификатор `async`.

И так возникает цепочка из методов с модификатором `async`, что как-то бросается в глаза и кажется, что что-то тут не то.

Вопрос в том:

"Пирамида" из `async` модификаторов- это нормально или может когда-нибудь потребоваться синхронно дождаться результата через `wait`?

Comment: _"Пирамида" из async модификаторов- это нормально_

Answer (score 2):

```
"Пирамида" из async модификаторов- это нормально?
```

Да

```
или может когда-нибудь потребоваться синхронно дождаться результата через wait?
```

Такое может быть когда вызывающий код не поддерживает асинхронность, например

- если вы постепенно переводите ваш код из синхронного в асинхронный (то есть не все вызовы поддерживают async),
- поддерживаете старые интерфейсы,
- если вызывающий код находится в сторонней бибоиотеке
- или вы используете асинхронные методы в геттерах/сеттерах (что очень не рекомедую).

Но вообще использование `.Wait()`, `.Result`, `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` считается [не оч хорошей практикой](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html), к такому надо относится с осторожностью.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, не *пирамида*, а *цепочка*.

Цепочка асинхронных вызовов это не просто нормально: только так и должен быть устроен асинхронный код.

Обычные потоки, когда вы их приостанавливаете, чтобы дождаться конца операции ввода-вывода, будут просто занимать ресурсы. Если одновременно к вашему веб-серверу будет 1000 обращений и вы пошлёте 1000 запросов к базе данных, у вас будет ровно 1000 остановленных потоков. На каждый поток ОС выделит 1 Мбайт ОЗУ, и планировщик потоков будет учитывать каждый из них что замедлит скорость работы системы в целом.

Вместо этого Windows предлагает специальные потоки: *чутко спящие*. Такой поток спит, но может быть разбужен системой, когда надо обработать результат операции ввода-вывода. Обработав результат, поток засыпает снова.

Обработка результатов не должна быть очень сложной. Обычно это что-то совсем простое: получили выборку из базы, сформировали HTML и отдали его клиенту. При таком подходе количество потоков может быть очень небольшим, например, для тех же 1000 клиентов вполне может хватить 10 потоков, потому что большую часть времени они ожидают ответа из БД, а когда он получен, быстро формируют HTML и готовы обрабатывать следующий ответ.

Требование *простой обработки* — очень важное. Если вы задержите поток своей обработкой, то планировщику задач придётся создавать новый поток.

Простая обработка это:
1. Быстрые вычисления. Если вам надо считать долго, попробуйте считать параллельно, или переносите обработку в фоновый процесс.
1. Никакой синхронизации потоков. Никаких семафоров, мутексов, мониторов и прочего. Поток, ожидающий сигнала будет находиться в обычном спящем состоянии, а в не чутком.
1. Никакого ожидания операций ввода-вывода. Такой поток также будет спать обычным сном.

Именно поэтому методы `async` нужно увязывать в цепочку. По сути это будет означать, что с самого глубокого метода в коде есть только ожидание ввода-вывода и простая обработка результатов.

Если последний метод в цепочке у вас очень простой, и не содержит операции ввода-вывода, можете использовать `Task.CompletedTask` или `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: `специальные потоки: чутко спящие` можно про это где то почитать?

Comment: `Требование простой обработки — очень важное. Если вы задержите поток своей обработкой, то планировщику задач придётся создавать новый поток` - какие с этим проблемы? Пусть создает. Разве, параллельный процесс не создаст то же самое (новый поток)? Или вы тут только про веб-сервер говорите?

Comment: `1. Никакой синхронизации потоков. Никаких семафоров, мутексов, мониторов и прочего` - вот это тоже не понял, есть дока про это? А как тогда управлять доступом к ресурсам? Я, например, бывает использую асинхронную блокировку семафором, какие с этим могут быть проблемы?

Comment: ну и тут вы пишете про операции ввода/вывода, но ожидать же можно не только их. Ваши рекомендации только по ожиданию ввода вывода или общие для всех случаев?

Comment: @tym32167. Почитать можно у Рихтера в книге CLR via C# (есть перевод на русском, ищите последнее издание). Можно читать документацию по Windows API. Начать можно с https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-queueuserapc

Comment: ага, я то только старое читал издание, спасибо, гляну на досуге

Comment: @MarkShevchenko,а какое издание последнее? 4-е?

Comment: @tym32167, похоже, что 4-е, где про .NET Framework 4.5 и C# 5. Есть ещё Джон Скит, "C# для профессионалов", но это уже на высоком уровне. Рихтер рассказывает о том, как это выглядит с точки зрения Windows API.

Comment: Да я обе книги читал, давно правда, уже лет 5-6 прошло, видимо пропустил или забыл этот момент с чутко спящими потоками. Но вообще ваши рекомендации имеют смысл для операций ввода/вывода в веб сервере, но этим же применение асинхронности не ограничивается, верно?

Comment: @iluxa1810 4-е вроде последнее

Comment: @tym32167 Два основных сценария применения асинхронности: десктопные приложения и серверы. К десктопным сразу относите и мобильные, они по той же схеме строятся. Серверы могут быть не только веб, но понятно, что Web и REST проекты встречаются чаще. Поддержка асинхронности в Windows появилась именно для операций ввода-вывода, наверное, в 99% случаев речь идёт о вводе или выводе. Речь идёт не только о файлах, но и запросах к БД, запросах к Redis и так далее. Но в принципе помимо ввода и вывода есть также вычислительные задачи.

Comment: ну, я про то, что, к примеру, рекомендация выполнять вычисления в параллельном процессе - я это могу понять для веб-сервера, где количество потоков на процесс сервера ограничено (пулом, например). Но в десктопах, например, это смысла не будет иметь, там делай потоков сколько хочешь, там не будет 1000 клиентов. да и 1000 тяжелых параллельных операций одновременно тоже не будет скорее всего, потому я не понял, зачем эта рекомндация на дексктопе.

Comment: По поводу вариантов применения, да, 90% - это I/O, хотя я, например, применяю это также для UI - например, ожидание заполненных форм от юзера - асинхронная задача, не связанная с I/O

Comment: @tym32167 На десктопе это нужно, чтобы пользовательский интерфейс был отзывчивым.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko да, это в случае фонового потока, но вы хе процесс рекомендуете фоновый,а не поток, я вот про него не понял и спрашиваю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89886/discussion-between-mark-shevchenko-and-tym32167).

Comment: К сожалению, на работе не могу в чат